# Running Silverlight Application Out Of Browser As default

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

we have a  silverlight Application In our company, which is hosted in a Web Application.
when I want to test the app, I should to start the web application, then right click on the page and then click on install button to install out of browser version of application.
I should do this each time I make a change on my C# code.

is there any way to start my application in Out-Of-Browser mode as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Righclick your project goto Properties - > Silverlight.

There enable the option like this

[image]

Comment: thanks, but read my question again carefully! I need my asp.net application (which silverlight application is hosted in it) to come up in OOB mode each time I play the application ( your settings are done in my project). your setting is correct when I start the silverlight application, not when I start asp.net web application!

Comment: If you are not using any service oriented actions in WEB project then you can ignore the hosting part. Else, you may use different WEB project and publish at IIS (either local or remote) and use the published service link in your Silverlight project with OOB settings.

Comment: hi i am using silverlight 5, i have added icon and every thing.
but icons not showing while open application. how to find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup your silverlight application as the StartUp Project and, in the project properties, set the "Installed out-of-browser application" to debug your project.

You can see this step by step here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamlew/archive/2009/07/28/debugging-silverlight-applications-in-out-of-browser-mode.aspx